# is it possible to change app permission ? android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

i want to upload a new app to google play store :

1. I want to implement app purchase in my app, but I will add it after 5 month.
2. currently at the registration process , I want to show this message for the user : you will get free premium app until `1-9-2015` .

3.so after `1-9-2015` I will create a product using google play console. and update the app

**question :**

***- first question :***

is there a problem with my plan ?

***-second question :***

at the beginning when somebody want to download the app using google play he should accept to this permissions ,without `in app purchase` permission :

[image]

then at 1-9-2015 he should accept to this permissions with `In-app purchases` :
[image]

but what will happen with the users who download the app before the new update, and didn't agree to `In-app purchases permission`

Answer (score 0):

When a user updates the app, they will be requested to approve any new permissions (in this case your in-app purchases permission). If they don't approve, they don't get the update and thus do not get in-app purchases. Even with automatic updates enabled, the user will still need to approve any new permission groups.

You can find more information [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=en).